# Can't pass JS parameters from VisuarlForce to Controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, parameters

I'm trying to pass 2 parameters from a VF page to a controller in order to reRender a pageBlockSection.

**Markup**

```
<apex:form>
            <apex:actionFunction action="{!setParameters}" name="sendParameters" reRender="work_Items" >
                <apex:param value="p1" assignTo="{!sDate}"/>
                <apex:param value="p2" assignTo="{!eDate}"/>
            </apex:actionFunction>
        </apex:form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getDateValues(){
            var startDate = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
            var endDate = $('#datetimepicker2').val();
            sendParameters(startDate,endDate);
        }
        </script>
         <div class='col-sm-3'>
                    Start Date: <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' onKeyup="sendParameters(1,2)" />
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm-3'>
                    End Date: <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker2' />
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm-3'>
                    <input type="button" value="Filter"  onClick="getDateValues()"/>
                </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public class AssigneRelatedWorkItemsController {
    public String eDate{get;set;}
    public String sDate{get;set;}
        
    public pageReference setParameters(){
        if(eDate != null && sDate != null){
           this.endDate = stringToDate(eDate);
           this.startDate = stringToDate(sDate);
        }
        System.debug(''+eDate);
        return null;
    }
    
    public Date stringToDate(String d){
        
        Date newDate = Date.valueOf(d);
        return newDate;
    }
}
```

But i'm having an issue, on the browser console I'm getting the following errors:

1. > SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters -->

   This is the ActionFunction script:

   ```
    <script id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id4" type="text/javascript">sendParameters=function(j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id5,j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id6){A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3',null,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id4','parameters':{'j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id6':(typeof j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id6!='undefined'&&j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id6!=null)?j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id6:'p2','j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id4':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id4','j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id5':(typeof j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id5!='undefined'&&j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id5!=null)?j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id5:'p1'} } )};
   ```
2. > ReferenceError: sendParameters is not defined

Console Screenshot:

[image: Console Log]

What could be wrong? Any Idea?

Comment: On keyup of StartDate why are you calling sendParameters()?

Comment: Oh, sorry @RahulSharma, I forgot to remove that. I was just trying to see if that would trigger the actionFunction

Comment: Can you post screenshot of JavaScript error in console?